# Retrieve station information from FM Radio using Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fm-radio

I'm having some fun with FMRadio class, in Windows Phone 8, but there is something I couldn't figure out how to do, retrieve station information.

Using the built-in radio app, for some stations some information appear on screen. This can be the name of the station, the name of the current show, the name of the current music. Does anyone know how to retrieve this kind of information? I believe it's retrieved from the FM signal itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> > **Caution:**
> >     FM radio is supported only in apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.
> >     If you use the FMRadio class in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0
> >     or later, a RadioDisabledException indicates that the FM radio feature
> >     is not available. On Windows Phone 8 devices with a build of 8.0.10322
> >     or greater, the run-time exception may not occur if you use the
> >     FMRadio API. However, the FMRadio API is not supported for apps that
> >     target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

None of the information you want was made available, and the radio support has been deprecated/removed.

Comment: This is out-of-date. I just successfully implemented a simple FM Radio app in my WIndows Phone 8 (very simple, jut turn it on and set the frequency).

Comment: But ok, even if it doesn't come from this library, there must be a way to retrieve the information, as a built-in app is able to do what I want. Any clue where I can find it? Didn't find anything on Nokia as well

Comment: How is the current documentation out of date? I don't follow. It says it might not throw an exception, but that it's **not supported**. Further, I answered that the information you wanted isn't available. It's likely only available to OEMs (well, was available).

Comment: Ok, so what is this guy using? http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/fm-radio/05d81d3f-9d8b-4e7c-8a13-08fb2ab67195. Guess I'll wait for 8.1 update to see if there are any news

Comment: Microsoft (and Nokia) is moving to streaming services for music. I wouldn't expect FM radio to show any improvements.

Comment: That's sad. Thanks for the help

Comment: re: not working with WP8, I am running WP 8.0.10517.150, and it (FM Radio) works just fine using a store app. What am I missing here?

Comment: Depends on the app -- and what version it targets as it states. It seems obvious that they aren't planning on keeping this feature around for new applications.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio

Version Information: .NET for Windows Phone apps;
**Supported** in: Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

Comment: The accepted answer does not answer the question, but rather gives an excuse why the person may encounter problems while developing.